# grid panel row height issue

Tags: extjs

I have an image + text in a column.when i chaange the width of the column the row height of grid panel is changing.I think it is because of the image because when i change the width of the other columns which dont have image in it row height doesnt chage.How  can i prevent this from happening.However this issue is not seen in firefox.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure every image in every row has the same height.

Comment: yes all the images are of same size.this dint solve the issue.Can you please help me out.